# deploy multiple file through saltstack only if all files are valid

Tags: salt-stack

We are managing web sites with saltstack. These sites run on PHP-FPM, and we have several fpm pools. Each pool is configured with dedicated file in `php-fpm.d/` directory.

Current, we have a `file.managed` state with `check_cmd: php-fpm -ty` to check if the configuration is valid.

```
fpm-conf:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/php-fpm.conf
    - source: salt://php/template/fpm.jinja
    - user: someuser
    - group: somegroup
    - mode: 644
    - template: jinja
    - check_cmd: /usr/sbin/php-fpm -ty
    - require:
      - pkg: php-package

fpm-pool-a:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/php-fpm.d/a.conf
    - source: salt://php/template/fpm-a.jinja
    - user: someuser
    - group: somegroup
    - file_mode: 644
    - template: jinja
    - require:
      - pkg: php-package
    - require_in:
      - file: fpm-conf

fpm-pool-b:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/php-fpm.d/b.conf
    - source: salt://php/template/fpm-b.jinja
    - user: someuser
    - group: somegroup
    - file_mode: 644
    - template: jinja
    - require:
      - pkg: php-package
    - require_in:
      - file: fpm-conf
```

It works fine, until mistake was made to a pool file (say, `fpm-pool-a`). Though the `fpm-conf` state blocks the update to the main fpm config file, the `a.conf` has been contaminated with erroneous configuration.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? It seems that `check_cmd` can't be used in this case.

How to guarantee that a series of files are all valid before updating?

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is recovering the original pool files if any mistakes were made.
Here is an example, I'd suggest start using jinja if this state start to get any larger.

```
fpm-conf:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/php-fpm.conf
    - source: salt://php/template/fpm.jinja
    - user: someuser
    - group: somegroup
    - mode: 644
    - template: jinja
    - check_cmd: /usr/sbin/php-fpm -ty
    - require:
      - pkg: php-package

fpm-pool-a:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/php-fpm.d/a.conf
    - source: salt://php/template/fpm-a.jinja
    - user: someuser
    - group: somegroup
    - file_mode: 644
    - template: jinja
    - require:
      - pkg: php-package
    - require_in:
      - file: fpm-conf
    - backup: minion

fpm-pool-b:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/php-fpm.d/b.conf
    - source: salt://php/template/fpm-b.jinja
    - user: someuser
    - group: somegroup
    - file_mode: 644
    - template: jinja
    - require:
      - pkg: php-package
    - require_in:
      - file: fpm-conf
    - backup: minion

fpm-pool-a-recover:
  module.run:
    - name: file.restore_backup
    - path: /etc/php-fpm.d/a.conf
    - backup_id: 0
    - onfail:
      - file: fpm-conf

fpm-pool-a-recover:
  module.run:
    - name: file.restore_backup
    - path: /etc/php-fpm.d/b.conf
    - backup_id: 0
    - onfail:
      - file: fpm-conf
```

Notice the `- backup: minion` addition, this will backup the file locally to /var/cache/salt/minion/file_backup/...

So in case the main config fails, fpm-pool-a-recover and fpm-pool-b-recover will fire and recover the most recent backup of the original file.